# Error when reading data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream

I have a filestream enabled database

I am able to write to the database but when I try to read the data back i get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: The user name or password is incorrect

The code I am trying to execute is this

```
public void ReadFromDatabase()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sql_ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(1) Video.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM Library", connection);

        SqlTransaction sqlTrans = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        cmd.Transaction = sqlTrans;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string path = reader.GetString(0);
                byte[] transContext = reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer;

                using (Stream fileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, transContext, FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, allocationSize: 0))
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                    fileStream.Read(data, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

                    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Georgi\AppData\Local\VideoPresenter\temp.mp4", data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using integrated security so the user and password are unchanged and hard coded into the application.

Here is the connection string code

```
//Create a string builder object
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
//Set the properties of the builder
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = false;
builder.DataSource = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
builder.InitialCatalog = "VideoLibrary";
//Set the connection string and connection objects' data
sql_ConnectionString = builder.ToString();
//try to connect to the server
```

And then I just use the string to open connections

The connection string passed is

> "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=VideoLibrary;Integrated Security=True"

Here is the stack trace

```
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(string path, byte[] transactionContext, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileOptions options, long allocationSize)   Unknown
System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.SqlFileStream(string path, byte[] transactionContext, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileOptions options, long allocationSize)   Unknown
```

> SQL FILESTREAM TEST CLIENT.exe!SQL_FILESTREAM_TEST_CLIENT.SQLOperations.ReadFromDatabase() Line 158 C#
>       SQL FILESTREAM TEST CLIENT.exe!SQL_FILESTREAM_TEST_CLIENT.MainWindow.GetButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 47   C#
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)    Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
>       SQL FILESTREAM TEST CLIENT.exe!SQL_FILESTREAM_TEST_CLIENT.App.Main()    C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown

When I open Management Studio I see the row that is filled with the data but I am not able to read it from the application

NOTE: There is the default SQL Server user 'sa' only. And I did try using it too but the result is the same. I create the database with the the Windows User and not with the 'sa' one

NOTE: If I am to run the code with a DataSource=(local) in the connection string it works.

NOTE: Database is in READ_WRITE mode

What I have tried:

I tried recreating the table and the whole database

I tried reinstalling SQL Server Express

I tried add features to Windows, particularly Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security -> Windows Authentication/Basic Authentication

I tried manipulating the rights of the user I am using but it is a dbo so there should be no problem.

I tried running the same code on a different machine (With the same Microsoft account)*

I tried setting tried to set FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL )

** I know that FileStream is working only with Windows Authentication and I am using windows 8 so everything is the same (or at least should be) in terms of accounts**
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are using integrated security then you should not specify any username or password in your connection string. The idea of integrated security is that the identity executing the process will be used to authenticate against the SQL database.

Comment: I don't specify them, I did try using SQL server authentication but the error is the same so I removed the user and password parameters from the connection string and now I only specify integrated security, datasource and initial catalog

Comment: Could you please show the connection string you are using and the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I updated it. About the AsyncProcessing I did try setting it to true and false.

Comment: The exact error is at the beginning of the question

Comment: Do you try to remove   builder.AsynchronousProcessing = false; from the builder and what is the value of the connection string in debug  when you give it to the command.

Comment: Removing the AsynchronousProcessing does nothing, same error occurs I will post the string in just a moment

Comment: As a side note, I strongly recommend you use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of allocating a buffer the size of the (potentially huge) file.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. Any idea why does this problem occur

Comment: Is this in a domain environment or in a workgroup?

Comment: It has to be integrated security to use the filestream, so the sa account will not work.  Are you sure you are correctly impersonating your current user and that you are not using the ASP.net identity (or NetworkService) to connect to your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I am to run the code with a DataSource=(local) in the connection string it works.

Because this works and using the IP Address does not, I suspect SQL Server is treating your connection as a remote connection instead of local.

Open **SQL Server Configuration Manager**. Select **SQL Server Services**. Locate the SQL Server instance you are using, right click and select **Properties**. On the **FILESTREAM** tab, select **Allow remote clients access to FILESTREAM data**.

If I am correct, that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you get a `Win32Exception`, not a `SqlException`, indicates that the issue occurs when you open the FILESTREAM. There are a number of steps you need to take to ensure remote FILESTREAM access via Win32 API (which is what you try to do). the important changes are to enable the Firewall on the server for port 445 (see [Configure a Firewall for FILESTREAM Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283098.aspx)) and (most importantly) configure the server to [Allow remote clients to have streaming access to FILESTREAM data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx). SQL configuration [filestream access level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645956.aspx) must be set to 2.

I also recommend going through the [Filestream Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480) whitepaper, if you still have problems. I've seen cases of mysterious FILESTREAM access denied errors ultimately being diagnosed as administrators messing with the filestream shared folders storage permissions.

I hope you already understand that FILESTREAM can *only* be accessed using integrated security. Integrated security **must** be used to obtain the handle path/context (your `SELECT` statement) and also *will* be used behind the scenes when using the Win32 API access (ie. when you try to open the SqlFileStream object).

Comment: First of all I did a check on the machine running the server. Ports are open (I am able to upload the file to the database) and the FILESTREAM is enabled for both T-SQL and file I/O access, Windows share name is set and I am allowing remote clients to access the FILESTREAM data. Everything is fine there. 

On the machine I run the client code (the one posted) I opened both ports the error still appears. So I am lost. I have no idea where the problem is coming from

Comment: And yes the filestream access level is set to two

Comment: I did read through everything you supplied and it seems everything is configured as it should be but the problem still persists

Comment: Can you add the entire stack of the exception?

Comment: If it was the stack trace of it I added it but I do now see anything interesting in it, I am not sure I understood what did you mean by 'the entire stack of the exception'

Comment: I'm more interested in the `[External Code]` part.

Comment: Where should I find it, there is a bunch of listings in the output windows but I don't know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: [How to: Use the Call Stack Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Value` instead of `reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer`. The buffer size isn't always the same as the value size. The buffer may contain garbage after the real data. By using the buffer, you may specify an invalid context.

Comment: It gives the same outcome

Answer (score 0):

You might have a delegation problem.
Assuming the following machine layout:

- clientPC - the machine running your software
- sqlSrv - your SQL-Server
- fStream - the machine with the filestream-share

You are working with integrated security, so *clientPC* is using Kerberos for authentication against *sqlSrv*. Then *sqlSrv* tries to authenticate the user for access to *fStream*, but fails.

This **might be** a Kerberos delegation scenario and you have to meet some requirements to allow that.
The service account, which runs your SQL Server process must be **trusted for delegation** (or constraint delegation). The delegation has probably to be allowed to the CIFS/fStream ServicePrincipalName.

Kerberos Constraint Delegation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553400.aspx
Some screens about Delegation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/autz_auth_stuff/archive/2011/05/03/kerberos-delegation.aspx
Infos about ServicePrincipalNames: http://blogs.iis.net/brian-murphy-booth/archive/2007/03/09/the-biggest-mistake-serviceprincipalname-s.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this Win32Exception was raised and handled within the WPF application stack?
You can experience this many times when debugging WPF applications, because it makes API calls and it could fail or handle the exception and continue the processing.